# Library to convert keycode to keysym at linux console

Tags: linux, console, keyboard-events

Using `evdev` (the kernel interface, not the X driver), I can listen for keyboard events and get keycodes. Is there a library interface to convert those to keysyms (again, those set by `loadkeys`, not `xmodmap`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not know any library can do that.

Maybe you want to take a look of the `dumpkeys` source, special the `codetoksym()` function. You can checkout the `kbd` (`dumpkeys` is part of it) source by the following command:

```
git clone http://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/legion/kbd.git
```